# Re-Use Alias SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

So I'm trying to accomplish this task Of the cities with the top five most zip codes, how many have a zip code with the string 09 in it?

I have the following to find the most zip codes

```
Select 
      City, 
      count(1) AS CountOrder 
FROM [dbo].['free-zipcode-database$']
Group by  City
Order BY Countorder Desc
```

Now how do I reuse the alias CountOrder to rank the top 5 and then have the string 09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT TOP 5
        City,
        -- Count of all zipcodes
        COUNT(*) CountOrder,
        -- Only count zipcodes that contain 09
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ZipCode LIKE '%09%' THEN 1 END) Zip09Count
FROM    [dbo].['free-zipcode-database$']
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY CountOrder DESC
```

Comment: @VisualExstasy please mark this answer as the answer to your question.